# How to find which user Deleted Store Procedures in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to find who deleted Store Procedure in MYSQL Database. All I got his

```
SELECT * FROM  mysql.general_log  WHERE user_host rlike '(user)+' ;
```

But not able to fetch anything .

Is there any best understandable way to recover the Deleted Store procedure or any other object in MYSQL.

Comment: MySQL have DDL log, of course, but it is service-only, it records only the statements performed during crash recovery operations, it is deleted during successful server start if exists, and it is not configurable. *way to recover the Deleted Store procedure or any other object* Regular backup is the best option.

Comment: @Akina I don't want recovery of procedure . I want to know which user deleted the object .

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute

```
show variables like 'gen%';
```

Ensure that `general_log` is ON.

Look for general log filename.

2. Execute

```
show variables like 'data%';
```

Look for data directory root path.

3. Go to the data directory root. Copy the general log file somewhere.
4. Open maked log copy in any text editor. Search it for `Query` event and `DROP PROCEDURE` statement, look for connection number.
5. Search the file from the line found to the start of file (up) for this connection number. Look for closest `Connect` event for this connection number, and look the account.

Comment: Is the general log the only way to see delete operations? For seeing who dropped a database too?